# ¿Como utilizar una function para insputs con el mismo nombre[]?

Tags: php, javascript, google-maps

tengo un código en php el cual quiero llamar a la function de google maps de auto-completado para el llenado de una plantilla
esto es lo que estoy usando.
el primer script es para añadir mas lineas dependiendo de la necesidad de direcciones

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
       /**
       * Funcion para añadir una nueva fila en la tabla
       */
       $("#add").click(function(){
      var nuevaFila="<tr> \
      <td><input type='text' name='direccion[]' id='direccion[]' class='form- 
       control'></td> \
      </tr>";
    $("#tabla tbody").append(nuevaFila);
    });

    // evento para eliminar la fila
      $("#tabla").on("click", ".del", function(){
        $(this).parents("tr").remove();
      });
   });
  </script>
```

entonces el html es en el cual funciona correctamente el auto completado pero solo en la primera linea

```
  <form action="" method="post">
    <table id="tabla" class="table" style="width: 100%;">
      <thead>
        <tr>
           <th scope="col">Direccion</th>
           <th><input type="button" id="add" value="añadir fila"></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td><input type="text" name='direccion[]' id='direccion[]' 
           class="form-control" autocomplete="off" placeholder="direccion"></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  <input type="submit" value="enviar">
 </form>
```

bueno aquí les dejo el script de google map para el auto completado

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?
key=YOUAPIKEY&libraries=places&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
<script>
function initMap() {
   var input = document.getElementById('direccion[]');
   var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
   autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function() {
       var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
       document.getElementById('location-snap').
       innerHTML = place.formatted_address;  
       document.getElementById('lat-span').
       innerHTML = place.geometry.location.lat();
       document.getElementById('lon-span').
       innerHTML = place.geometry.location.lng();
   });

}
</script>
```

la pregunta es existe la posibilidad de hacer funcionar ese script en en todas los input que requiera en su momento?

Comment: Daniel, lo que quieres es agregar mas inputs, por ejemplo uno de Lat, Long, etc y autocompletar esos inputs tambien no solo el de direccion?

Comment: gracias por responder y no, quiero poder usar la function de auto-completado en  varios campos input name="direccion[]" ya que la cantidad de campos dependerá de la cantidad de direcciones